# Hyperledger Fabric: What is the difference between state store and crypto store?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

HL Fabric supports a state store and a crypto store as can be seen [here](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-network-config.html) for example. But what is the difference between these two stores? It looks like both will store some kind of secrets but what store is used for what?

Some links I found but none of them address the question:
https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABN-643

https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Client.html  says:

> The client also supports persistence via a stateStore. A state store
>   is a simple storage plugin that implements
>   the module:api.KeyValueStore interface, which helps the SDK save
>   critical information to be used across server restarts/crashes. Out of
>   the box, the SDK saves the signing identities (instances of
>   the User class) in the state store.

So we think we have some idea of what the state store is used for. But what is cryptoStore used for then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crypto store stores the public and private keys.

[image]

State store stores the public X509 certificate plus some metadata and a pointer to the keys in the crypto store. In image below, the `signingIdentity` is the pointer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

cryptoStore stores the private keys. State store stores the certificates obtained from  fabric-ca